# Pass a variable from Site.Master.cs to Site.Master

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameter-passing

I'm new to C# web development. Please bear with me.

I'm trying to reference a param from Site.Master.cs in Site.Master, so that in Site.Master page, I can do:

```
<%
  if (someParam == true) {
%>

some HTML code

<%
 }
%>
```

The param someParam is the one I want to pass from Site.Master.cs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below code example.

Site.Master.cs

```
protected bool someParam
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Site.Master page

```
<%
  if (someParam) {
%>

some HTML code

<%
 }
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a class-level field (or better: property) with visibility at least "protected" (not private).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LiteralControl`.

```
<asp:Literal ID="myControl" runat="server">
// Some html here.
</asp:Literal>
```

Then in the codebehind - set the `Visible` property appropriately.